# unable to add a new column to a pandas dataframe from within a function

Tags: python, pandas

it_json are columns that contain lists, for each row in a dataframe I want to add the lists
in a fresh column called full

```
def list_columns(df):
    df2=df.copy()
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        # print(row)
        l=[]
        if row['it_json_1']:
            l+=row['it_json_1']
        if row['it_json_2']:
            l+=row['it_json_2']
        if row['it_json_3']:
            l+=row['it_json_3']
        if row['it_json_4']:
            l+=row['it_json_4']
        df2['full'][index]= l
    return df2
```

but list_columns(df) is giving me key error
[image]

Comment: *df2['full'][index]= l* command works when there already is a column named 'full'. First we need to create it. df2['full'] = "" in the beginning

Comment: It is also possible to just add the columns, provided null values are replaced with empty lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating values to a column that doesn't exist yet, so create an empty column before adding values.

```
def list_columns(df):
df2=df.copy()
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    # print(row)
    l=[]
    l['full'] = np.nan
    if row['it_json_1']:
        l+=row['it_json_1']
    if row['it_json_2']:
        l+=row['it_json_2']
    if row['it_json_3']:
        l+=row['it_json_3']
    if row['it_json_4']:
        l+=row['it_json_4']
    df2['full'][index]= l
return df2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the values into a list then assign them to the new columns "full"

```
 full.append(l)
```

then after the loop ends:

```
 df2['full'] = full
```